# Why doesn't my Grid update when I add children in dispatcher?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, kinect, dispatcher

I'm running a fairly simple task with the kinect, just trying to display data streams using the polling method. I am running all of my processing on a backgroundworker, and using dispatcher to update the UI.

The code below works fine for depth and color streams that write to a bitmap in the dispatcher. However, displaying the skeleton requires a Grid with children (polylines). This code runs without error, but does not update the UI to show the line. What do I need to do to make the UI refresh the Grid and show the child objects?

```
this._SkeletonGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
     joints = new[] { JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ShoulderCenter };
     this._SkeletonGrid.Children.Add(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));                          
}));
```

_SkeletonGrid is the xaml Grid object, CreateFigure returns a polyline.

Comment: Are you running this in a tight loop? Your BeginInvoke call may be falling behind. What about the sizes and dimensions? Are you drawing a single dot? I assume you only have one row and column in that grid?

Comment: @Brannon i'm trying to draw a single line (for now). The grid is: <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="640" Height="480"></Grid>, where _SkeletonGrid = LayoutRoot. I'm not sure what you mean by running a tight loop.

Comment: Have you verified that you can add a line using CreateFigure outside of your BackgroundWorker thread? What you have written looks like it should work fine to me but there may be other components in the layout that are causing the Grid to actually not be visible. Additionally, are you making sure to clear the grid before adding the Polyline to SkeletonGrid?

Comment: @julenka Yeah, this code definitely works in the UI thread, just not in dispatcher. I do have a clear slightly earlier, in a similar dispatcher block.